# How to get the nearest Vector to a given target from a list

Tags: java, opengl

So imagine I've created a `Vector` class with two variables `x` and `y` in Java:

```
public class Vector {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Vector(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;  
    }

    public int getY(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

Then I've craeted an `ArrayList` of vectors:

```
private List<Vector> vecs = new ArrayList<Vector>();
```

I've created in that list:

```
8,9
10,5
83473834,938849584985
etc ...
```

Now I want to get the closest vector to another vector.
Example:

```
private List<Vector> vecs = new ArrayList<Vector>();
private Vector vec = new Vector(1,1);

for(Vector vector:vecs) {
    //What do i put here??
}
```

So what do i put in the for loop to make it select the nearest vector from the vector list?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you haven't tried anything yet, you could start by iterating over each vector in the list, and comparing them to `vec`; keep track of the closest one, until the algorithm is finished or you find an exact match.  Start by assuming the first in the list is closest, then iterate over each and compute distance.  Whenever you find one that's closer than the one you were keeping track of, mark it as the closest, and continue from there.  There are probably ways to simplify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by adding a method to the `Vector` class, `distanceTo`, that calculates the distance from this vector to another one:

```
public double distanceTo(Vector vec) {
    double dx = x - vec.x;               //calculate the diffrence in x-coordinate
    double dy = y - vec.y;               //calculate the diffrence in y-coordinate
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);     //use the distance formula to find the difference
}
```

And then you can write the following method that returns the closest vector in a list to a given vector:

```
public static Vector closest(Vector target, List<Vector> list) {
    Vector closest = list.get(0);                                 //this variable will kep track of the closest vector we have found yet. We simply start with the first one

    for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {                        //loop over the list, skipping the first entry
        Vector curr = list.get(i);                                //get the current vector from the list
        if (target.distanceTo(curr) < target.distanceTo(closest))    //if the current vector is closer to target than the closest one yet
            closest = curr;                                       //keep the current vector as the new closest one
    }

    return closest;                                               //return the resulting vector
}
```

This method can then be used like this:

```
Vector target = new Vector(1, 2);

List<Vector> vecs = new ArrayList<Vector>();
vecs.add(new Vector(-2, 6));
vecs.add(new Vector(1, 3));
vecs.add(new Vector(4, 0));
vecs.add(new Vector(8, -1));

Vector closest = findClosest(target, vecs);
```

As you can see I tried to explain the code as best as I could, but feel free to ask any further questions!

EDIT another method is:

```
 public double distanceTo(Vector vec1,Vector vec2) {
        double dx = vec2.x - vec1.x;               //calculate the diffrence in x-coordinate
        double dy = vec.y - vec1.y;               //calculate the diffrence in y-coordinate
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);     //use the distance formula to find the difference
    }
```

This is if you can't put it into the vector class

Comment: But shouldn't it be like:

Comment: if (target.distanceTo(curr) < target.distanceTo(closest <-----))

Comment: @Caspermartijn Yes you are absolutely correct, I edited my answer. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic programming question. It is not related to OpenGL. A simple linear search could look as follows:

```
private List<Vector> vecs = new ArrayList<Vector>();

private Vector vec = new Vector(1,1);

Vector minDistanceVector = null;
int minDistanceSquared = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(Vector vector : vecs) {
    //Calculate the distance
    //This could be a member function of Vector
    int dx = vector.getX() - vec.getX();
    int dy = vector.getY() - vec.getY();
    int squaredDistance = dx * dx + dy * dy;

    if(squaredDistance < minDistanceSquared) {
        minDistanceSquared = squaredDistance;
        minDistanceVector = vector;
    }
}
```

After that, you will have the closest vector in `minDistanceVector`. I chose Euclidean distance because this is probably what you want. But you could use any other distance, of course.

If you want something more efficient, you may want to build some acceleration data structure over the points and query that one (e.g. grid, kd-tree, quadtree...).